# Reading Multiple Pickle files using Apache-Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pickle

I am learning Apache-Spark now, and I'm just wondering if I can use the method `wholeTextFiles` from `SparkContext()` to read multiple files with format ".pkl". For example,

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("haha").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
temp = sc.wholeTextFiles("mydir/*.pkl")   ### The directory of Pickle files.
```

is it possible to use `wholeTextFiles` to read pickle files? If not, is there any way to do that? I really appreciate if anyone helps me.

Comment: Hello Ruofan. I'm interested on that. Did you find a solution?